# Converting a list of ints, tuples into an numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, tuples

I have a list of [float, (float,float,float..) ] ... Which is basically an n-dimensional point along with a fitness value for each point. 
For eg.

```
4.3, (2,3,4)
3.2, (1,3,5)
.
.
48.2, (23,1,32)
```

I wish to randomly sample one point based upon the fitness values. I decided the best way to do this would be to use `numpy.random.choice(range(n), 1, plist[:,:1,:1])`

However, i need to convert this into an numpy array, for which i tried

```
>> pArr = np.array( plist ) 
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

I got the same error for np.asarray(plist) as well.. any suggestions??

Comment: afaik np arrays must be of all elements of the same type...

Comment: Is it possible to convert it into a 3 dimensional array? or do i change the formation of this list itself to make it 3 dimensional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
A = np.array([tuple(i) for i in initial_list],dtype=[('fitness',float),('point',(float,3))])
```

with `initial_list = [[4.3, (2, 3, 4)], [3.2, (1, 3, 5)], ...]`. Note that we need to transform each item of `initial_list` into a tuple for that trick to work, else NumPy cannot recognize the structure.

Your fitness entries are now accessible as `A['fitness']`, with the corresponding points as `A['point']`. If you select a list of actual fitness entries, `indices`, the corresponding points are given by `A['point'][indices]`, which is a simple `(n,3)` array.

Comment: That does work thanks!! but does not really help in this situation. Since i am trying to slice out the fitness values for random selection. Which brings me back to the initial problem of slicing one dimension in a multi dimensional array ...!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is difficult to understand.  Is this what you're trying to do?

```
>>> x
[[4.3, (2, 3, 4)], [3.2, (1, 3, 5)], [48.2, (23, 1, 32)]]
>>> np.array([(a, b, c, d) for a, (b, c, d) in x])
array([[  4.3,   2. ,   3. ,   4. ],
       [  3.2,   1. ,   3. ,   5. ],
       [ 48.2,  23. ,   1. ,  32. ]])
```

Comment: Well, the fitness is different from the coordinates, and i would like to keep it that way.. But I guess i could do this and add 1 where ever i wish to access the coordinates!

Comment: The only problem being that, my dimensions are variable. So I may have (b,c,d) or (b,c,d,e...) in the tuple, can this be generalized?