# Each item in DataFrame column is list of different dimension - how to proceed?

Tags: python, mysql, numpy, pandas

My issue is similar to [Converting a list of ints, tuples into an numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253447/converting-a-list-of-ints-tuples-into-an-numpy-array) but different in that each item is not necessarily of the format [float, (float, float, float)] but the first is [float, float] and the next is [float, float, float], etc.

The data in my DataFrame is obtained from querying a mySQL database, if that matters. The 'values' column was originally populated by strings of the format "1,2" and "1,2,3" and "1,2,3,4,5" and so on.
The DataFrame now looks roughly like:

```
ID       values            num
1        [1, 2]             2
2        [1, 2, 3]          3
3        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    5
```

What I want to do is be able to take each [float, float, ...] entry from the DataFrame and report new values/variables based off of it to new columns appended to the same DataFrame, such as calculate the standard deviation of each 'values' list or the new variable ' avg = sum(values)/num ' and store the results in df_new['stddev'] or df_new['avg'].

And here's the portion of my code I'm focusing on so far:

```
df_new = df[df.num <= 10]
df_new['values'] = df_new['values'].astype(str).str.split(',')
valList = df_new.values.tolist()
```

I'm relatively new to Python so bear with me if I'm missing out on something basic.

Answer (score 0):

```
df_new = df[df.num <= 10]
df_new['values'] = df_new['values'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: map(float, x))
df_new['avg'] = df_new['values'].apply(np.mean)
df_new['stddev'] = df_new['values'].apply(np.std)
```

yields

```
   ID           values  num  avg    stddev
0   1           [1, 2]    2  1.5  0.500000
1   2        [1, 2, 3]    3  2.0  0.816497
2   3  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    5  3.0  1.414214
```

Comment: I tried that, and the code makes sense, but I'm getting an error "cannot perform reduce with flexible type" - do I have to manually convert each list to an array, or something like that?

Comment: I tried using a for loop, but received the same error:            for row in df_new_new['editPercents']:
    eP_mean = np.mean(row)
    df_new_new['eP_mean'] = eP_mean

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem is due to `values` being a list of *strings* instead of a list of floats. A quick patch would be to define `df_new['values'] = df_new['values'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: map(float, x))`. But really, this is just a band-aid pasted over a bigger problem. You shouldn't be forming a DataFrame with a column which is a comma separated list of numbers. If that's the way the data is stored in the database, then the database needs to be fixed. It should be storing numbers as numbers, not strings.

Comment: Also, storing Python lists in a Pandas column is very inefficient. You'll get much better performance if you expand the number of rows in your DataFrame so that each value gets its own row. Ideally, you would want to pull the data out of the database and into this DataFrame completely avoiding the problems you are currently facing. Then the values you are looking for could be computed with `df.groupby(['ID'])['val'].agg(['mean','std'])`.